# MobileAds.initialize(Context, String) is deprecated

Tags: java, android, admob, deprecation-warning

Before it looked like this (passing `R.string.admob_application_id`):

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_application_id));
```

---

[`MobileAds`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds) method `.initialize(Context context, String applicationCode)` 
now reads:

> This method is deprecated. Use [`initialize(Context, OnInitializationCompleteListener)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds#initialize(android.content.Context,%20com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener)) instead.

Which reads:

> Initializes the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
>   Call this method as early as possible to reduce latency on the session's first ad request.
>   If this method is not called, the first ad request automatically initializes the Google Mobile Ads SDK.

[MobileAds.Settings](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds.Settings) also had been deprecated.

---

What I have tried so far is to get the [`InitializationStatus`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/initialization/InitializationStatus) per adapter:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {

    /* get the adapter status */
    Map<String, AdapterStatus> map = initializationStatus.getAdapterStatusMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, AdapterStatus> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        AdapterStatus adapterStatus = entry.getValue();
        AdapterStatus.State state = adapterStatus.getInitializationState();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "key = " + entry.getKey() + ", state = " + state.name() + ", desc = " + adapterStatus.getDescription());
    }
});
```

On an emulator it says `READY`, but `.getDescription()` has a rather confusing message:

```
Google Mobile Ads SDK initialization functionality unavailable for this session.
Ad requests can be made at any time.
```

On a physical device with internet connection it shows four more adapters:

```
key = com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds, state = READY, desc = 
key = com.google.ads.mediation.vungle.VungleMediationAdapter, state = NOT_READY, desc = Failed to create Adapter.
key = com.google.ads.mediation.applovin.AppLovinMediationAdapter, state = NOT_READY, desc = Failed to create Adapter.
key = com.google.ads.mediation.adcolony.AdColonyMediationAdapter, state = NOT_READY, desc = Failed to create Adapter.
key = com.google.ads.mediation.tapjoy.TapjoyMediationAdapter, state = NOT_READY, desc = Failed to create Adapter.
```

`om.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds` reads `READY`, the other `com.google.ads.mediation.*` read `NOT_READY` and `Failed to create Adapter` (there is no [mediation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediate) set up, but it can load test ads).

`MobileAds.initialize(this);` also works (`OnInitializationCompleteListener` is optional).

---

It seems to work without the `R.string.admob_application_id`, therefore my actual question is:

Is setting `R.string.admob_publisher_id` and `R.string.admob_application_id` still required - or is it only the ad-unit ID now? Most of the documentation still uses the deprecated initialization method (alike the one shown above), therefore this isn't clear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Get started with AdMob in your Android project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start) seems to answer the application ID part:

> Add your AdMob App ID to your app's `AndroidManifest.xml` file by adding the `<meta-data>` tag as shown below.
>
> Important: This step is required as of Google Mobile Ads SDK v17.0.0. If you don't add this `<meta-data>` tag, your app will crash with the message: "`The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly.`"

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ADMOB_APP_ID"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And the publisher ID still is required for [Requesting Consent from European Users](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent).

Comment: How do you set Publisher ID for Xamarin?

Comment: Just the same ...I'd assume.

Answer (score 13):

Initialize MobileAds with the following instead:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> { });
```

Comment: 2021 not working anymore